# What does flags 02000002 mean in /proc/pid/fdinfo/fd_num?

Tags: linux, proc

There is a python process running on Linux version 3.2.0 and hangs on `epoll_wait(6, ...)` for hours, then I use `cat /proc/24924/fdinfo/6` command to find more information about the file descriptor.

```
$ cat /proc/24924/fdinfo/6
pos:    0
flags:  02000002
```

I have searched [linux man-pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and know that the octal number of flags displays the file access mode and file status flags, so what does `02000002` exactly means?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK octal value of 02000002 consists of two flags: O_CLOEXEC and O_RDWR.
O_CLOEXEC is the flag which means that this file descriptor will be closed in case of invoking exec function. O_RDWR means opeening for reading and writing. More description you can find in man 3 open.

Comment: Man 3 open  page is useful, and it seems that file descriptor flags cann't help me find out why the process hangs, thanks.

Comment: It seems like the process is waiting for something on file descriptor 6 - maybe it is some kind of network socket?